# Can a reaction happen if a product change phase under reaction conditions?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

Suppose we have the reaction :

$$\ce{A(s) + B(s) <=> C(g)}$$

The equilibrium constant will be equal to $e^{-\frac{Δ_rG}{RT}}$ and it varies with temperature. Suppose that $\ce{A}$ and $\ce{B}$ come into contact at temperature $T$ and pressure $p$ where the phase diagram for $\ce{C}$ at these conditions correspond to liquid phase. Will the reaction take place at all? I mean if it takes place but all the gas that is produced is converted into liquid then the reaction quotient will be zero at all times. But shouldn't at some time the reaction reach equilibrium with $K=p^{eq}_{c}$? Are equilibrium constants meaningfull only if the conditions allow for the compounds to be in the physical state that the chemical equation indicates?

After reading the comments I felt that I should add some details. If the reaction is happening in a closed vessel then we can combine the reactions ($1$), ($2$) to get ($3$):
\begin{align}
\ce{A(s) + B(s) &<=> C(g)} & (1)\\
\ce{C(g) &<=> C(l)}          & (2)\\
\ce{A(s) + B(s) &<=> C(l)} & (3)
\end{align}

What if the reaction takes place at open vessel so that all gas turns into liquid?

Comment: No, the equilibrium constants are always meaningful. See, a liquid has a certain vapor pressure above it.

Comment: If A+B is very rapid vs C condensation, an equilibrium may be established rapidly in the vapour phase and so a K(gas) may be measurable. Then as C liquid forms, the reaction proceeds further as the vapour pressure above the liquid C is smaller than the pressure of C as a gas. If A+B reaction is v slow then equilibrium is that between liquid C  and A+B. The end result is the same. Thermodynamics only concerns itself with final equilibrium conditions, i.e A(g)+B(g)=C(liq).

Comment: Note that $K = \exp\Big({-\frac{\Delta_rG^\circ}{RT}}\Big)$. Don't forget that you have to use the standard states for calculating $K$. Moreover, it would be more meaningful to measure $K$ for $\ce{A(s) + B(s) <=> C(l)}$ at low temperatures.

Comment: Scratch that last. How would you even measure an equilibrium constant for the last one...

Comment: Based on your edit I think one of your misconceptions is that you think that C will always be a gas first, but in reality most C particles will just aggregate to a liquid directly at low temperatures.

Comment: I bet $\ce{A(s) + B(s) <=> C(l)}$ behaves similar to phase transitions. So there will be a certain $T$ analogous to a melting temperature that dictates on which side the equilibrium lies. $K$ is no longer meaningful, since concentrations of solids and liquids are treated constant.